# If value found in column, copy it to certain elements in row

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to prepare a tool which searches for anything in certain column, and if see anything, copy this value and paste this in few elements on its row

For example if in G2 there is value "ADD", then A2+B2 + E2 + F2 would be an "ADD" to (except C)

Its very hard for me to overcome obstacles, so far I came up with that.. I know this code is hard to bear with but I rarely use VBA so i never had a chance to learn so its mix of what I've found here on stackoverflow combined as per my requirements

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

wb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ws = Application.ActiveSheet

With ws

Set myRange = Range("G1", Range("G1").End(xlDown))

For i = 1 to myRange

if i <>"" Then

Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Select
Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Value = i.text

[I know this part will do from the first element of A to the last but I dont know how to choose elements I wish if they're not one next to each other]

Next i
End with
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do, it seem you don't need to declare "wb" and "ws". Vba default will use the ActiveSheet. Also wb is declared to be workbook, but ActiveWorkbook.Name is acutally an text. Your code will encounter error.

If you want to loop from G1 to its last inputted cell, you can refer to following code:
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count,7).End(xlUp).Row

The rows.count refer to the last row (1048576) in excel. and "end(xlup)" will find the last cell which inputted value at G column. And the ".row" return the row number of the last cell.

Similarly, you can use "Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)" to find the last column's cell inputted at row 1

You may try below code:

```
For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

If Cells(i, 7).Value <> "" Then

Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).Value = Cells(i, 7).Value
Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Value = Cells(i, 7).Value

End If

Next i
```

However, You mention you want to copy except C column. Since I dont know what actual condition that you will not copy to the column. I just simply separate the code into 2 parts, one for A and B column, another one for D to the last columns

Answer (score 0):

One option could be the following:

```
Sub FindAndCopy()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, searchRng As Range, cl As Range, searchTerm As Variant
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    With ws
    
        Set searchRng = .Range("G1", .Range("G1").End(xlDown))
    
        searchTerm = "ADD"
        
        For Each cl In searchRng
            If cl = searchTerm Then
                Range("A" & cl.Row) = searchTerm
                Range("B" & cl.Row) = searchTerm
                Range("E" & cl.Row) = searchTerm
                Range("F" & cl.Row) = searchTerm
            End If
        
        Next cl
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: "ADD" was an example, there could be really anything, therefore I need this if its not blank/empty/you name it in the column then it needs to be copied and pasted in desirable columns

Comment: In which case modify the code appropriately. For example *if not cl = vbNullString And not IsBlank(cl)...etc*